# Correct procedure for advanced permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I've googled this extensively, but can't get my head around it. 
I have a few custom post types and a taxonomy (location).

I can access all the post types in a **location** via:

> www.example.com/location/(location)

I can access all the **post types** via:

> www.example.com/(custom-post-type)

Lastly, I can access a specific **post type** in a specific **location** via:

> www.example.com/location/(location)/?post_type=(custom-post-type)

The above URL is generated via two SELECT dropdowns:

```
<select name="post_type"> and <select name="location">
```

My question is: How can I remove "?post_type=" from the URL and return just:

> www.example.com/(custom-post-type)/location/(location)

or even just change "?post_type=" to something else, ie:

> www.example.com/location/(location)/?event=(custom-post-type)

Is something like this possible? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!